# Reference problem : Package inputenc Error- Keyboard character used is undefined

Tags: errors, cross-referencing, bibitem

I have a problem with one of my references in the below code, it complains about the **third** one with:

```
Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined
```

and here is the code:

```
\documentclass[runningheads,a4paper]{llncs}

    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}

    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{booktabs}


    \usepackage{mathtools}

    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage{booktabs,array}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{hhline}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hhline


    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}


    \begin{document}


\begin{thebibliography}{4}

\bibitem{jour} Othmane, Lotfi ben, Ranchal, Rohit, Fernando, Ruchith, Bhargava, Bharat,  Bod-den, Eric. (2015). Incorporating attacker capabilities in risk estimation and mitigation. Comput. Secur., 51(C), 41-61. doi: 10.1016/j.cose.2015.03.001

\bibitem{book} Alberts C, Dorofee A. Managing Information Security Risks: The OCTAVE Approach, Addison-Wesley Professional.2002.

\bibitem{jour} Schneier, B.: Attack Trees. Dr. Dobb’s Journal (1999).

\bibitem{proceeding1} Czajkowski, K., Fitzgerald, S., Foster, I., Kesselman, C.: Grid
Information Services for Distributed Resource Sharing. In: 10th IEEE
International Symposium on High Performance Distributed Computing, pp.
181--184. IEEE Press, New York (2001)

\bibitem{proceeding2} Foster, I., Kesselman, C., Nick, J., Tuecke, S.: The Physiology of the
Grid: an Open Grid Services Architecture for Distributed Systems
Integration. Technical report, Global Grid Forum (2002)

\bibitem{url} National Center for Biotechnology Information, \url{http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov}

\end{thebibliography}



    \end{document}
```

Comment: Your items have identical names, this is not good.

Comment: Did you just create that file with a modern computer? Try substituting `latin1`  with `utf8`.

Comment: Your bibliography is formatted inconsistently. Please have a look at https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Manually_Managing_References

Comment: it's a springer template comes from here
ftp://ftp.springer.de/pub/tex/latex/llncs/latex2e/llncs2e.zip
or
https://www.springer.com/gp/computer-science/lncs/conference-proceedings-guidelines

Comment: Is there any news here?